# regular expression for password ignored

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, regex

I wrote this javascript and html code to check validity of username and password.For some reason regular expression for password is being igonred.

```js
function checkDetails() {
  var uname = document.getElementById("uname").value;
  var pass = document.getElementById("pass").value;
  var reuname = /^[a-zA-Z]\w*$/;
  var repass = /^\w+{4,8}$/;
  if (reuname.test(uname)) alert(uname);
  else {
    alert("username should be alphanumeric and start with alphabet");
    return false;
  }
  if (repass.test(pass)) alert(pass);
  else {
    alert("password should be alphanumeric with 4-8 chars");
    return false;
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  background-color: cyan;
}
#content {
  width: 550px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
h1 {
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}
#content table td {
  height: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div id="content">
  <h1>Register Form</h1>
  <form method="post" action="" onsubmit="return checkDetails(); return false;">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>Enter UserName:</td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" name="uname" size="20" id="uname" />
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Enter Password:</td>
        <td>
          <input type="password" name="pass" size="20" id="pass" />
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Re-Enter Password:</td>
        <td>
          <input type="password" name="repass" size="20" id="repass" />
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Enter E-mail:</td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" name="email" id="email" />
          <td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Re-Enter E-mail:</td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" name="reemail" id="reemail" />
          <td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Enter Address:</td>
        <td>
          <textarea rows="10" cols="50" name="address" id="address"></textarea>
          <td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="2" style="text-align: center;">
          <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" style="width: 100px; height: 30px;" />
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </form>
</div>
```

When i comment this particular line, however it works.

```
/*var repass = /^\w+{4,8}$/;*/
```

Why is this weird behaviour?

Comment: What do you mean it's being "ignored"?

Comment: the execution proceeds without checking `uname`

Comment: Did you check your console? You have a syntax error in your regular expression.

Answer (score 2):

Check your console! You should see there: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: /^\w+{4,8}$/: Nothing to repeat(…)`

I'm not sure what you wanted exactly, but maybe try this instead `/^(\w+){4,8}$/`

Comment: Do you know what your regex matches? Hint: it does not make sense.

Comment: It probably doesn't XD I don't know what he wanted it to match. The major point was that the syntax was incorrect

Comment: how can someone upvote this answer ?!

Comment: The question was "Why is this weird behaviour?". The answer is "because this line raises an exception". I also added a pretty bad example for a correct-syntax regex that would not raise an exception. What's the problem?

Answer (score 2):

```js
function checkDetails() {
  var uname = document.getElementById("uname").value;
  var pass = document.getElementById("pass").value;
  var reuname = /^[a-zA-Z]\w*$/;
  var repass = /^\w{4,8}$/;
  if(reuname.test(uname))alert(uname);
  else {
    alert("username should be alphanumeric and start with alphabet");
    return false;
  }
  if(repass.test(pass))alert(pass);
  else {
    alert("password should be alphanumeric with 4-8 chars");
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}
```

```css
body{
  background-color: cyan;
}
#content{
  width: 550px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
h1 {
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}
#content table td{
  height: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div id="content">
  <h1>Register Form</h1>
  <form method="post" action="" onsubmit="return checkDetails(); return false;">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>Enter UserName:</td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" name="uname" size="20"
          id="uname" />
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Enter Password:</td>
        <td>
          <input type="password" name="pass" size="20"
          id="pass" />
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Re-Enter Password:</td>
        <td>
          <input type="password" name="repass" size="20"
          id="repass" />
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Enter E-mail:</td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" name="email" id="email"
          />
          <td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Re-Enter E-mail:</td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" name="reemail" id="reemail"
          />
          <td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Enter Address:</td>
        <td>
          <textarea rows="10" cols="50" name="address"
          id="address"></textarea>
          <td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="2" style="text-align: center;">
          <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit"
          style="width: 100px; height: 30px;"
          />
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </form>
</div>
```

I think the regex for password was not valid. Can you try this.

Answer (score 1):

You have to remove the '+' sign of your regular expression.

```
var repass = /^\w{4,8}$/;
```